# Datatables for personal use

Tags: jquery, django, datatables

I am making a project for a friend of mine who runs a dental clinic. The project is about managing appointments, adding customer etc.
The project is in Django and I used Jquery Datatables plugin in the project..I am planning to deploy the project on web so he could access the patients info add/edit anytime anywhere he wants.
However will this be violating the policy of Datatables plugin? Since i don't have the purchased license.

Answer (score 0):

As far as below conditions, if you included the copy right it should not be an issue.

https://datatables.net/license/